# Transposing SQL table

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot

I have the following tables (tables below are simplification of more complex task):

abc.FirstTable

```
ID | Name
---------
10 | test
```

abc.SecondTable

```
Id | RefId
----------
20 | 10
21 | 10
```

What I want to have is:

```
Id | Name | RefId1 | RefId2
---------------------------
10 | test | 20     | 21
```

I am stuck with:

```
select t1.id, t1.name, t2.ID from abc.FirstTable t1
left join abc.SecondTable t2 on t2.refid = t1.id;
```

which produces two rows. Any tips on how to extend this query using joins? Thank you!

Comment: Are you okay with using `pivot`, or you wish to use only left join?

Comment: How many `refid` might you find in the second table, for a single `id` from the first? Is the number known ahead of time? If not, then you will need dynamic SQL - but first you will have to decide that you really need to do this (often that is a sign of poor logic), and if you do, that you need to do it IN SQL and not in your reporting application (which is the much better place for such manipulations).

Comment: https://oracle-base.com/articles/11g/pivot-and-unpivot-operators-11gr1

Comment: I expect only two refids in the second table. I prefer solution with left join. The real case I'm working on actually requires use of four tables and more complex solution but I think if I figure it out for this simple case, it would be easier for me to do my task

Answer (score 1):

```
with t as
( 
  select t1.id id1, t1.name, t2.* from abc_FirstTable t1 join abc_SecondTable t2 on t2.refid = t1.id
)
select * from t
pivot
(
 min(id) min_id, max(id) max_id 
 for (refid) in (10)
);
```